# Insert into SQL Derby using column indices instead of column names

Tags: java, sql, insert, derby

Is there any way to insert into a Derby database in java by using the column index instead of the column name?

Example:

`INSERT INTO myTable (5) values ('PUT THIS IN COLUMN INDEX 5')`

Where 5 is the index of a column, not the column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an updatable [resultset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) and named columns:

```
ResultSet updates = connectionObject.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE).executeQuery("select id, foo1, foo2 from footable);
updates.moveToInsertRow();
updates.updateInt(1, 34); // updates id
updates.updateString(2, "bar"); // updates foo1
updates.updateBoolean(3, true); // updates foo2
updates.insertRow();
connectionObject.commit();
```

I hope this helped, if you have further questions, do leave a comment.

Comment: This is close. This still requires that I need to know the column names. Is there a way to just say `select * from footable` and then be able to work with all of the columns in my table? I can also assume that the tables are empty when I call this.

Comment: I'm not sure if the column order is guaranteed in a SELECT * statement, try it and see?

Comment: This will work fine. Using the `ResultsSetMetaData` I can get the column count and column names. I ran it a couple hundred times and the column names came up in order every time. I now have a couple different solutions to my problem I need to choose from (which is never a bad thing). Thanks!

Comment: Oh, right, I'd forgotten about the ResultSetMetaData class. However, SQL best practices tend to favour named columns in your result sets.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/reference/sqlj40.html#INSERT+statement) the insert statement only supports column names not indexes.
(took me less then 5s to google that)

Comment: And, while you are correct, using JDBC, there is a way to accomplish what OP wants, see my answer.